# Google Speech Recognition Library in Python has Extremely Slow speech_to_text() Times

Tags: python, runtime, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

As the title states, I am trying to do a continual listening AI named Sapphire using the speech_recognition library. For about one minute after starting the code fresh it works fine, however, after it has been running for more than a minute, the speech_to_text() takes forever to run.

Any help would be appreciated, I am looking for some form of solution to this issue. Perhaps I am not understanding the functions well enough, or there may be a way to stop the speech_to_text() function after a certain time.

I am running a texting/email version of the bot as well in addition to the voice version using threading, but I was having this problem with speech_to_text() before threading was involved.

Thank you for your help!

Here is the output:

```
Me  -->  Sapphire what time is it
speech_to_text() Time =  5.611827599990647
Sapphire -->  16:46.
Listening...
Me  -->  ERROR
speech_to_text() Time =  3.4650153999973554
Listening...
Me  -->  ERROR
speech_to_text() Time =  6.241592899998068
Listening...
Me  -->  ERROR
speech_to_text() Time =  12.198483600004693
Listening...
Me  -->  ERROR
speech_to_text() Time =  3.7981161000061547
Listening...
Me  -->  shoe stamps
speech_to_text() Time =  51.52946890000021
Listening...
Me  -->  ERROR
speech_to_text() Time =  6.57019980000041
Listening...
Me  -->  ERROR
speech_to_text() Time =  46.647391800011974
Listening...
```

Here is my code to run the Sapphire AI:

```
class ChatBot():
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("----- Starting up", name, "-----")
        self.name = name

    def speech_to_text(self):
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        # with sr.Microphone(device_index=3) as mic:
        with sr.Microphone() as mic:
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic)
            print("Listening...")
            audio = recognizer.listen(mic)
            self.text="ERROR"
        try:
            self.text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            print("Me  --> ", self.text)
        except:
            print("Me  -->  ERROR")

    @staticmethod
    def text_to_speech(text):
        if text == "":
            print("ERROR")
        else:
            print((ai.name+" --> "), text)
            speaker = gTTS(text=text, lang="en", slow=False)
            speaker.save("res.mp3")

            vlc_instance = vlc.Instance("--no-video")
            player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()

            media = vlc_instance.media_new("res.mp3")

            player.set_media(media)
            player.play()


    def wake_up(self, text):
        return True if (self.name).lower() in text.lower() else False


def parse_input(txt):
    ## action time
    if "time" in txt and "is" in txt and "it" in txt:
        res = action_time()
    elif ai.name.lower() in txt:
        res = np.random.choice(
            ["That's me!, Sapphire!", "Hello I am Sapphire the AI", "Yes I am Sapphire!", "My name is Sapphire, okay?!", "I am Sapphire and I am alive!",
             "It's-a Me!, Sapphire!"])
    ## respond politely
    elif any(i in txt for i in ["thank", "thanks"]):
        res = np.random.choice(
            ["you're welcome!", "anytime!", "no problem!", "cool!", "I'm here if you need me!",
             "mention not."])
    elif any(i in txt for i in ["exit", "close"]):
        res = np.random.choice(
            ["Tata!", "Have a good day!", "Bye!", "Goodbye!", "Hope to meet soon!", "peace out!"])
        ex = False
    ## conversation
    else:
        if txt == "ERROR":
            # res="Sorry, come again?"
            res = ""
        else:
            starttime1 = timeit.default_timer()
            chat = nlp(transformers.Conversation(txt), pad_token_id=50256)
            endtime1 = timeit.default_timer()
            print("Transformer Time = ", (endtime1 - starttime1))
            res = str(chat)
            res = res[res.find("bot >> ") + 6:].strip()
    return res

def sapphire_audio():
    ex = True
    start = 0
    while ex:
        starttime1 = timeit.default_timer()
        ai.speech_to_text()
        endtime1 = timeit.default_timer()
        print("speech_to_text() Time = ", (endtime1 - starttime1))
        ## wake up
        if ai.wake_up(ai.text) is True:
            #remove Sapphire from phrase
            ai.text = ai.text.lower().replace(ai.name.lower(), "", 1)
            if start == 0:
                res = "Hello I am Sapphire the AI, what can I do for you?"
                start = 1
            else:
                res = parse_input(ai.text)
            ai.text_to_speech(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.environ["TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM"] = "true"

    # sapphire_email()
    threading.Thread(target=sapphire_email).start()
    threading.Thread(target=sapphire_audio).start()
```

Comment: The best way that I have found is to record about 2-3 seconds of audio in SoundDevice or Pyaudio and then save it to a file and then use SpeechRecognitions recognize from file function (check the docs for that I can't remember) The built-in Microphone() and listen() methods are pretty bad in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - try to measure what method takes that long time to execute. Is it the `listen()` method or `recognize_google()`?

Try using function `recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic)` just once in the beginning, and not every time when you use `speech_to_text()` function and see what will happen after that.

Function `recognizer.listen(mic)` waits for audio from your microphone to come down to some threshold set by `recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic)`.

I assume that sometimes threshold is set so low and to achieve that level of ambient noise you need to wait very long time. (Check your mic in audacity? Listen to that and analyze if ambient noise changes from time to time?)

Also you are sending that audio to Google server using public API key. It's only a guess but maybe some additional delay is provided with sending long length audio data using not that great home internet upload speed. And perhaps Google, since you are sending many requests on public API key, isn't prioritizing your requests which can lead to another delay.

But it's just a guess. Try to do what I wrote at the beginning and we will figure it out.